# Java increment/decrement var and order of operations

Tags: java, operator-precedence, post-increment

```
public class ForTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int y = 0; 
        int x = y++ + y*5; 

        
        System.out.println(x);
    }
    
}
```

Why is the output of this expression equal to fiveL I understand that the `y++` takes precedence so `y*5` equals `5`, but in that case shouldn't `x` equal `6`?  My conundrum is that if `y*5` equals `5` than doesn't that imply that `y` has already incremented and thus meaning that `x` should equal 6?

Comment: 0 + 1 × 5 = 5 .

Comment: `y++` increments the variable but returns the _old_ value. So `y++ + y*5` evaluates to `0 + 1*5` in your example. That said, `++y` increments the variable and returns the _new_ value. So if you had `++y + y*5` then that would evaluate to `1 + 1*5`.

Comment: It is about the order evaluation of operands in one expression. These are evaluated one after one. Not after the whole expression. That means, in your expression `y++ + y*5` (1) operand `y++` is evaluated to `0` and then y is incremented to `1`, afterwars (2) the operand y (in `y*5`) is evaluated to `1`, which will turn to `1*5`. For more informations, have a look at section 2.5.1.6 of http://www.cs.ait.ac.th/~on/O/oreilly/java-ent/jnut/ch02_05.htm